# SQL Server Query - How to get approvers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of documents in a table "Documents" with Function, Tier, Locations and Product Line fields.

[image]

I need to get approvers names from another table `Approvers` based on Library (aka Function), Tier (aka Level), Location and Product Line. (If document table says All Location then in the approver table "Any Location" = Yes. If in the Document Table "Product Line = NOT PRODUCT LINE SPECIFIC" then in the APPROVERS table "Any Product Line = "YES".

[image]

I am attaching a list of approvers for each document.

[image]

I have this SQL query but it's pulling approvers name but doesnt match the  3rd picture in the post. for example, if I want to get approvers for document # 5 then it should get "David, Debbie, Moe, Steven, Dan" .

```
select 
    APPROVERS
from
    approvers
where
    (libraryname = 'OPERATIONS' 
     and level = 'A' 
     and (ProductLine = 'whatever product' or AnyProductLine = 'Yes'))
    or
    (libraryname = 'OPERATIONS' 
     and level = 'A' 
     and (Location = 'whatever location' or AnyLocation = 'Yes'))
```

Comment: (Update) Doesn't match how, what's the actual result? Could you post a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? Also, is the reason you aren't using a JOIN just for demo purposes?

Comment: No I cannot join tables. I am not allowed to touch the "Documents" table. I can touch the "Approvers" table and feed data from the "Documents" fields.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4b34cd/1

Comment: They won't even allow selecting from it in a join? Weird...

Comment: yes, it's a sharepoint database and the approver tables is in a separate db. for the testing purpose I can manually input the product line and location values.

Comment: For #5, why is Maurino excluded from the desired results? His AnyLocation  value is set to 'Yes'

Comment: he can only approve all product for broken arrow only

Comment: The way the statement is currently written, it matches on either ProductLine OR Locations, not both.  Changing the SQL to use `AND` instead would fix that, but would exclude Steven because his ProductLine doesn't match that of the Document.  "COMPRESSION AND PRODUCTION PLANTS" vs "COMPRESSION"

Comment: anyway to re-write the query so the approvers matches this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YRQu.png

Comment: Changing the match on ProductLine to use a wildcard would work for #5, i.e. `LIKE '%COMPRESSION%'`. However, if there are other discrepancies between the ProductLine values in documents and assigneeds, it may not always yield the desired results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cf949/4

Comment: I wonder if we need to re-do the approvers table or re-write the query differently so that document 1 thru 9 yields appropriate approvers. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YRQu.png. For now, I am okay with hard coding product or location in the query to get the desire result. I see multiple selection is allowed for product line and i dont mind foreach loop run the same query few times to get a solid end result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qfd0.png

Comment: BTW there are so many other ProductLine and Locations so I can run for each and loop through each PL and same for locations.

Comment: Can I please get some ideas about the query?

Comment: Tbh, still not following *why* those are the expected results, despite looking over the images several times. Maybe it's the table structure, but there seem to be too many exceptions.... Perhaps someone else will have suggestions. May help to lay out the actual rules and requirements in plain english, not just the expected results.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help...

Comment: @SOS: good point. I will write up a summary.